# Python: using function on 2 elements of different 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to get the sum of the equivalent indexes of 2 arrays and then threshold them. This code runs but very slow and I have to use this function very often. Is there a more efficient way in python?

```
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(smoothed,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=-1)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(smoothed,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=-1)

for i in range(0,height-1):
    for j in range(0,width-1):

        xvalue= sobelx[i,j]
        yvalue= sobely[i,j]
        tmp = math.sqrt(math.pow(xvalue,2) + math.pow(yvalue,2))

        if tmp > 255:
            tmp = 255
        elif tmp <0:
            tmp =0

        self.gradientmap[i,j] = tmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(smoothed,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=-1)
sobely = cv2.Sobel(smoothed,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=-1)

self.gradientmap = numpy.sqrt (sobelx ** 2 + sobely ** 2)
self.gradientmap[self.gradientmap> 255] = 255
```

I don't know what is the exact type of `sobelx` and `sobely` but I assumed there were 2 `numpy.array` from your questions.

**Note:** I removed the `tmp < 0` case because you will never have a negative square root.